# TinyMCE disable toolbar buttons when on a specific content in the editor

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have configured TinyMCE for a specific div. However, in this div, there are some child content that are not editable. Considering the following HTML:

```
<div class="editor">
    <p> Hello World </p>
    <p> This is a test </p>
    <div class="special-div">
        <p> Hello test </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have set up the TinyMCE as such:

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: ".editor",
   inline: true,
   toolbar: ["formatselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist"]
})
```

In this case, I would like that when the user clicks on the `.special-div`, the toolbar buttons are disabled.

I have tried playing around with the `selector` parameter such as:

```
selector: ".editor :not(.special-div)"
```

However it does not work. I also found that there is a parameter called `editor_deselector`, but this is only for TinyMCE v3, and I am using v4. I found that it might be possible to do it by using the internal TinyMCE apis such as setting each button to the disabled state but I was wondering if it's possible to do it out of the box.

The main concern is the toolbar itself and not the content, with `mceNonEditable` or even `contentEditable="false"`, I can prevent TinyMCE from applying anything to it. It's more of a user experience question as I don't want people to think that they can format `.special-div`.

If it's not possible to have them disabled, is there a way to just hide the toolbar when I select `.special-div`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ctrlmanager;
editor.onNodeChange.add(function (editor, controlManager, node) {
                ctrlmanager = controlManager;
controlManager.setDisabled('lngQuoteList_Uk', (node.nodeName == 'TD' || $(node).parents('TD').length > 0) || (node.className == 'del cts-1' && node.nodeName == 'SPAN'));
 });
```

Comment: you can add your condition as per requirement.